# Numpy broadcasting alignment issues

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am having difficulty understanding an error with a broadcasting operation when using data generated by an external library (lhsmdu 1.1) with numpy 1.18.1.

I use it to generate a (10, 5) np.ndarray which I then scale with a couple of (5,) np.ndarrays. But even though it seems that the shapes of all arrays in the operation seem okay for broadcasting, I still get:

```
ValueError: shapes (10,5) and (1,5) not aligned: 5 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

I did some tests to try to understand this, because at this moment I really don't:

```
import numpy as np
import lhsmdu

ub = 2.0 * np.ones(5)
lb = 0.5 * np.ones(5)
k = lhsmdu.sample(ub.size, 10)
try:
    z = k.T * (ub - lb) + lb
except ValueError:
    print("failed original problem")

# 1 - numpy copy
a = np.copy(k)
try:
    z = a.T * (ub - lb) + lb
except ValueError:
    print("failed test 1")

# 2 - just copy shape
b = np.ones_like(k)
try:
    z = b.T * (ub - lb) + lb
except ValueError:
    print("failed test 2")

# 3 - copy shape and values
c = np.empty(k.shape)
for ix in range(0, k.shape[0]):
    for iy in range(0, k.shape[1]):
        c[ix,iy] = k[ix,iy]
try:
    z = c.T * (ub - lb) + lb
except ValueError:
    print("failed test 3")

# 4 - deepcopy
import copy
d = copy.deepcopy(k)
try:
    z = d.T * (ub - lb) + lb
except ValueError:
    print("failed test 4")
```

Which outputs:

```
failed original problem
failed test 2
failed test 4
```

What trivial thing am I missing here?

Comment: That's not a broadcasting error.  It's issued by `dot` or `matmul/@`.  It's matrix mulriplication.

Comment: `lhsmdu.sample` returns a `numpy.matrix`, for which `*` is matrix multiplication.  A quick fix is to use `k = lhsmdu.sample(ub.size, 10).A` (The `.A` attibute converts the `matrix` to a regular numpy array.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser then deepcopy and np.ones_like return a np.matrix, while np.copy returns a np.ndarray when given a np.matrix. Thanks. if this warrants an answer, I'll accept it if you post it.